# Добавление поля в двумерный массив в цикле

Tags: php

В общем есть массив

```
$a1 = array('car1' => array('color' => 'black',
                                    'weight'=> '100'),
             'car2' => array('color' => 'white',
                                    'weight'=> '200'));
```

Я не знаю как в цикле добавить новое поле ‘*type*’ в массивы '*car1*' и '*car2*' с каким-то своим значением например ‘*легковая*’, ‘*грузовая*’ соответственно.
Получается только добавление в массив *$a1*.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($a1 as &$car){
    $car['type'] = 'легковая';
}
```

Ну или если есть отдельная коллекция категории машин

```
$carTypes = ['car1' => 'легковая', 'car2' => 'грузовая'];
foreach($a1 as $name => &$car){
    $car['type'] = $carTypes[$name];
}
```

Comment: Только надо не забыть удалисть ссылку на `$car` после цикла: `unset($car);`

Comment: @postrel, Я бы не стал это делать - будет лишняя строчка захламляющая код. Код должен быть изящным, ИМХО.

Comment: Можно, конечно, и не захламлять, но зато получить вот такой результат: https://3v4l.org/IMCWM

Answer (score 1):

```
$typeNames = array('car1'=>'легковая', 'car2'=>'грузо
foreach(array_keys($a1) as $v)
{
  $a1[$v]['type'] = 'легковая';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

или ко всем остальным ответом `array_map`

```
array_map(function($n) {
    $n['type'] = getType() // функция для вычисления type car
},$yourArray);
```